# .Net Core 3.1 MVC - Authorization - How to log successful or failed logins?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, authorization

I'm trying to understand how I can log the successful or failed login of a user when using Authorization.

I've been looking at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0 without getting a clear idea of how to proceed.

My current `ConfigureServices` in Startup.cs, where I setup Active Directory authorization:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
    services.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);            
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {                                
        options.AddPolicy("ADRoleOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole(Configuration["SecuritySettings:ADGroup"]));
    });
    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();

        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });

    services.AddLogging();
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}
```

Comment: You can define a authorization handler and use that for logging. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: You can check the `policyBuilder.RequireAssertion` and in function definition the `RequireRole` can be evaluated; However that would bring another question how to inject `ILogger` in `ConfigureServices` method of .Net 3.1

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Have to figure it out somehow. I've previously looked at the guide, without making anything of it.

Comment: Go for `IAuthorizationRequirement` and handler implementation where you can inject the required services and use it.